# Porting Add-on SDK to Webextension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-57+

I hope someone can help me with webextensions in Firefox 57.
Im trying to port an plugin from Add-on SDK to Webextension.

All I have is this following code

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "myPlugin",
  "title": "Grafic",
  "id": "myID",
  "main": "lib/main.js",
  "description": "myDescription",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MPL 2.0",
  "version": "1.0.1"
}
```

and the main.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

browser.tabs.getCurrent is indeed only for background scripts. What you want is simply window.location.href.

Answer (score 1):

To get the URL of a page when it becomes active, you could use:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {
  if (!document.hidden) {
      console.log('URL: ' + location.href);
  }
}, false);
```